# onclick event not invoking a javascript function

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Below code in controller and a function getSug(). all this code is inside a angular controller. onclick event doesn't invoke getSug() function. How do i invoke it?

```
var vm = this;
var quant ="linkClick";
vm.link = '<a onclick="'+vm.getSug();+'">' + quant + '</a>';

function getSug(){}

html:  <table>
            <tr>
              <th>link</th>
              
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td ng-bind-html="vm.link"></td>
             
            </tr>
          </table>
```

Comment: Why do you need to build the anchor element in this way, as @Kinglish mention in AngularJs you should be using `ng-click`.

Comment: only because these links are built using a map and there are multiple links formed dynamically in controller code using the result of an API. i didn't show here to keep it simple

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In angularjs, onclick is `ng-click`

Also you wouldn't write your html that way in angular. Rather it would be:

```
<table>
 <tr>
  <th>link</th>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>
    <a ng-if='quant' ng-click="getSug()" ng-bind-html="quant"></a> 
  </td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Then your function would live in the controller that was associated with that page:

```
$scope.getSug = function() {
   // code
}
```

Comment: i need to invoke it through controller code in the way i  declared variable, not this way.

Answer (score 0):

The function `getSug` gets called on the 3rd line.

Instead of `onclick` function you just invoke it at the definition line.

Use

```
var vm = this;
var quant ="linkClick";
vm.link = '<a onclick="'+"vm.getSug()"+'">' + quant + '</a>';

function getSug(){}
```